# How inform event head and admin of new team registered in Ruby on Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm making a website in Ruby on Rails which includes a registration page where teams can register for a particular event. Events are selected from a select option. As soon as a team registers for a particular event, I want website to send email to site admin and event head informing the same. How to proceed with this?

Comment: What exactly do you want help with? Sending an email via Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) area linked above, you will find information on how to ask questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sending an email via RoR whenever a new user registers.

Comment: You need to be more elaborate on what exactly you need. Also, you should provide at least some code that shows that you have tried something before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

For sending email from your RoR application, Rails developers use [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

So let's say you want to send an email to the the users within a team as soon as the team registered for an event. 
You could do something like this:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'your_email_address_for_example@example.com'

  def registration_email(team)
    @users = team.users
    @url  = 'http://example.com/event/registration'
    @users.each do |user|
     mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Thank you for registering to this event')
    end
  end
end
```

The `registration_email` method takes the team as a parameter. Each team has many users and so we want iterate through all the users in the team and send and email to each one of them.

Comment: Actually sending email to team members is not my concern but sending the email to admin of the website and the one who is organising the particular event for which team registered for, is bugging me. And email should list all the team members.

Comment: Do you have the email of the admin associated with the event the team registered for? That should be in the event table, a column like `:admin_email`